# Can't connect my django backend with Postgrsql

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

In my dockerized project, I'm trying to connect my Django app with Postgresql but it keeps giving me this error:

```
File "/home/cr_user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

**My compose.yml**

```
   version: '3.9'

  services:

    db:
      container_name: db
      image: postgres:13
      ports: 
        - '5432:5432'
      env_file:
        - ./server/.env
      volumes:
        - dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
      networks: 
        - cr_nginx_network

    cr_api:
      container_name: cr_api
      build:
        context: ./server
        dockerfile: Dockerfile    
      command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5000
      ports:
        - "5000:5000"
      volumes:
        - ./server:/cr_server
      depends_on:
       - db
  volumes: 
    dbdata:
    pgadmin_data:
    
  networks:
    cr_nginx_network:
      driver: bridge
```

**My settings.py**

```
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]

 DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': os.environ.get("POSTGRES_NAME"),
        'USER': os.environ.get("POSTGRES_USER"),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get("POSTGRES_PASSWORD"),
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432
    }
}
```

The postgres container is running without a problem but I can't see causing the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68548725/docker-django-db-utils-operationalerror-could-not-translate-host-name-db-to-a)

Comment: The issue was that I was not properly setting the network to be external and also provide for every service where I want it to be used. But thanks a lot for your help @journpy

Comment: The two containers aren't on the same `networks:`.  The easiest solution will be to delete all of the `networks:` blocks in the entire file; Compose will create a network named `default` and attach both containers to it.  Also see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.

Comment: That's correct @DavidMaze. Thanks